Print dataframe from command
I was wondering whether there is a way to send a dataframe or a plot (that I have in my R environment) directly to the printer, without having to save it as a document, open it and print it from libre office/adobe reader softwares. Do you know about a way to do it ?
Thank you for your help !

Have you tried the "Print" command under "File" in R Studio?

Hi Lily, this seems like a duplicate of the linked question - if your issue is different, please edit your question to describe exactly how and I can reopen it. Hope this helps and good luck!
